# How to prevent cross site script attacks using javascript

Tags: javascript, xss

In my application, i have used excel like grid using MVC3. Recently we faced cross site scripting attack issue while testing in the grid by typing  'alert('hack')' in grid cell which is simply an input textbox. This results in executing the script and an alert is displaying. How can i avoid executing the scripts using javascript?

Comment: what do you mean by "in the grid"? can we see the code? it is a lot easier to help you if you put in on jsfiddle.net and link it to us.

Comment: If a user is *typing* into your page, then it isn't a cross-site scripting attack.

For it to be XSS, the data would have to come from another site (e.g. a link or form with the data that triggered the alert embedded in it).

Comment: If you do have an XSS problem, then you probably shouldn't be trying to defend against it with JavaScript - defend against it at the point you inject the submitted data into the page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a good way to prevent websites from xss attacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012145/what-is-a-good-way-to-prevent-websites-from-xss-attacks)

Answer (score 0):

If that's all they needed in order to inject code then your grid must be using 'eval' - unless you comfortably accomodate only arithemetic expressions and cell references in your grid (and have the capability to implement this filtering) then you can't really solve the problem.